# When do not use "that"?

Tags: word-usage, syntax

While reading some phrases examples I saw this:

> These are the plates I want.

Translating to Portuguese gets this way:

> Esses são os pratos que eu quero.

As you can see the word "Que" means "That", apparently in my language, the word that is more usual. I think That(?) I'm using more "that" than is needed and I can't get when to not use.

> It really feels that(?) needs an "that" here.
>   ----------------------------↓
>   These are the plates * I want.

Comment: In non _wh_ relatives, the subordinator "that" is omissible except where 'gap' is in subject position, e.g. "I met some friends [that __ saw Ed last week]", where gap is subject of the bracketed relative clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relativizer (*that* or a *wh-* word) which introduces a restrictive relative clause **may** be omitted in all registers if it designates a constituent other than the subject in the relative clause. In your example, for instance, *that/which* would designate the direct object of *want*, so it may be omitted.

The relativizer is usually omitted in speech, except when the speaker is groping for words—in this case, speakers will often include *that*, and even repeat it as a useful 'filler'. In formal discourse it should be included if your sentence is long or complicated, because including it helps the reader parse your meaning. I myself prefer the appropriate *wh-* word in such contexts, because *that* has so many uses besides that (!) of relativizer that (!) it is as likely to confuse the reader as help her.

Note, by the way, that even a subject relativizer may be omitted in casual speech:

> There's this guy <s>who</s> lives down the street from me <s>who</s> has a reciprocating saw I borrow to prune trees.

This should not be emulated in formal registers.